# Change auto-brightness levels without rooting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, screen-brightness

On my Android 4.4 device, is there a way to change the auto-brightness values without rooting the device, e.g. by writing a tiny application?

Comment: apps exist that attempt to perform this function. do any of them work with 4.4?  "what have you tried?"

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible or you can use one of existing solutions on Google Play (for example [Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitocassisi.luxlite))

EDIT: OFC it works with 4.4, using it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) changes brightness below what is possible using auto or manual settings. It works on Android 4.4. Great for bed time reading.

Correction - (and contrary to the down vote) it does let you set the Auto Brightness Level to a level below what it normally would be - without rooting. I just tested it.